# androidx.paging.LoadState$NotLoading cannot be cast to androidx.paging.LoadState$Error | PagingCompose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3, android-paging-library

Event Handler

```kotlin
pagingFLow.apply {
    when {
        loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading -> {}
        loadState.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading -> {}
        loadState.append is LoadState.Loading -> {
            item { CircularProgressIndicator() }
        }
        loadState.refresh is LoadState.Error -> {
            val e = pagingFLow.loadState.append as LoadState.Error
            Log.i("ERROR", e.toString())
        }
        loadState.append is LoadState.Error -> {
            val e = pagingFLow.loadState.append as LoadState.Error
            Log.i("ERROR", e.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Here `val e = pagingFLow.loadState.append as LoadState.Error` throws `androidx.paging.LoadState$NotLoading cannot be cast to androidx.paging.LoadState$Error`

This works fine with DataSource without DB but When you add RemoteMediator it throws this error.

Comment: Your when checks for `loadState.refresh` and then you're trying to cast `pagingFLow.loadState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As philip dhukov alluded, you are making a cast which is not guaranteed to succeed

`loadState.append` can be anything in the following:

```
pagingFLow.apply {
    when {
        ...
        loadState.refresh is LoadState.Error -> {
            val e = pagingFLow.loadState.append as LoadState.Error
            Log.i("ERROR", e.toString())
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

You actually probably meant:

```
pagingFLow.apply {
    when {
        ...
        loadState.append is LoadState.Error -> {
            Log.i("ERROR", loadState.append.toString())
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Note: You dont need to explicitly cast after type check due to smart casting so you can omit the cast entirely.

Also, it is *generally* not safe to access a member and assume the value won't change in case of race conditions, so you should use `loadState.member` instead of `pagingFLow.loadState.member` in case this is called concurrently. Although it may be fine for your case it will also prevent kotlin from smart casting after type check